# Can Apple Watch read aloud web sites or web pages?

Tags: text-to-speech, speech

I know that Apple Watch comes with Siri, which is capable of understanding spoken phrases and respond with a short answer.

But can it also read an entire website or web page, similar to Android apps like Culinary Pal or Wiki Pal?

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: @Buscar웃 On the Apple Watch I did not try it because I did not buy one yet. On the Android I tried it and it is very impressive.

Comment: AFIK Apple Watch needs iPhone to access Internet. So reading on iPhone is a piece of cake.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I have an iPhone and so far I have not been able to find in the AppStore any app like [Culinary Pal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yizri.voculinary). That's why I am asking. I have been waiting for Apple to come up with something like this. If the Apple Watch has the ability to navigate through and read *any* web site, I will buy it. But from your answer I understand that it doesn't. Please correct if I am mistaken. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Out of box Apple Watch has almost no web functionality. Technically it can open web views from emails or Siri, but apps can't have its own web views and those web views can show only stripped down content and not do much more than that.

In general Apple disables this because most people would be frustrated if this was called browsing experience as it barely works but it is legitimate that for some people it may be useful.

So if you are after the full browsing experience Apple Watch is not for you.

However if you are interested into listening to the pages that you have got through the iPhone (or even from desktop if you enable a Pocket connection in Speech Central) using the text-to-speech then currently there are two apps that support something like that - Speech Central and Voice Dream Reader.